# Make a constant list of some data in application

Tags: c#, class

In my application, i want to have a list like this

```
Group  Kind   TableName   Condition
-----  ----   ---------   ----------
sh      Send    TableA      Null
sh      New     TableB      kbsn=0
jn      Receive TableC       Null
```

This list must use in whole of my application and it's values always is constant.
Now,how do i define this list in a class in my C# application and how can i read or query from this list?

Comment: Is [way of representing immutable list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612054/what-is-the-best-way-of-representing-an-immutable-list-in-net) what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Class and add fields to it.

Here is a code:

```
Class MyCustomClass
{
    public string Group { get; set; }   
    public string Kind { get; set; }  
    public string TableName { get; set; }  
    public string Condition { get; set; }  
}
```

Define static list of MyCustomClass and initialize in application at proper place and use it everywhere in application.

```
static List<MyCustomClass> lstMyCustomClass  = new List<MyCustomClass> { .... };
```

Comment: Add **readonly** after static and expose it as `IEnumerable` or `IReadOnlyCollection` (in .Net 4.5) in order to prevent modifications by its clients.

Comment: can you use ImmutableList or ReadOnlyCollection ?

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the following code, which I hope will solve your problem.

First of all, you have one class for all enums, so that you can declare all list components:

```
public enum GroupEnum
{
    sh,
    sh,
    jn
}

public enum TableNameEnum
{
    TableA,
    TableB,
    TableC
}

public class MyCustomClass
{
    public GroupEnum Group { get; set; }
    public KindEnum Kind { get; set; }
    public TableNameEnum TableName { get; set; }
}
```

When you make list type object of `MyCustomClass`, you have all static values of group, kind, and table name etc. so that you can filter that list according to that static values through LINQ in C#.